# username and password error handling

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to put some traps but it didnt work. I can login with wrong username and password. What is the possible solution for this?

```
  foreach ($result as $row) {
  $acc_username=$row['acc_username'];
  $acc_password=$row['acc_password'];
  $acc_tableid=$row['table_id'];


  }

  if ($result == 0){
   echo '
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.
   </div>';
  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   window.location.href='tableLogin.php';
   </SCRIPT>");
} 
else{
    $_SESSION['table_number'] = $_POST['Make'];
    $_SESSION['table_idd'] = $row['table_id'];
    header("Location: customerLogin.php");
}
  $update = "UPDATE tables SET login_status=1 WHERE table_id= $table_id";
    if(mysql_query($update)){
        }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
} ?>
```

Comment: How do you get `$result`, can you post your DB query too.

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT account.acc_username,account.acc_password, tables.table_id FROM account INNER JOIN tables ON tables.table_id=account.table_id  WHERE tables.table_number='$makerValue' AND account.acc_username='$uname' AND account.acc_password='$pword'");
     
     
      $stmt->execute();
      
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are doing your initial database query before the section of code that you posted but if you are doing fetchAll to get the rows out of the database then it may be a matter of replacing

```
if ($result == 0){
```

with

```
if (empty($result)){
```

to cater for no users found and errors in the SQL query.

**Edit:** I meant fetchAll

Comment: No worries. Tick the question as answer if that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (empty($result) ){
```

or

```
if (count($result) == 0 ){
  //show alert
}
else
{
//update login status
}
```